# with php, how to embed a newline in an output string

Tags: php, newline

Is there a way to get something like the following php snippet to produce two lines (ie., 'xxx' and 'yyy', respectively), rather than both on a single line? (I'm running php under Windows 11.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php

$s = 'xxx';
$s .= '<BR>';
$s .= 'yyy';
echo nl2br($s);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works as expected when I test it.  (And the use of `nl2br` is superfluous.)  How are you testing it?

Answer (score 2):

Do you want html output, or the formatted source code to have line breaks?

Your string will have a 'newline' (ie an HTML line break) if displayed as HTML already, but the source will be a single line, because you are not adding any line end characters in your text.

Calling `n12br($s)` does nothing, as it is a function that inserts `<br>` in front of the standard line end characters  (either '\n' on Unix or '\r\n' on Windows), and you don't have any newline characters in your string.

Try:

```
<?php
    $s = "xxx<br>\n";
    $s .= "yyy\n";
?>
```

Will output in a browser as:

```
xxx
yyy
```

and in the HTML source as:

```
xxx<br>
yyy
```

If using Windows, use "\r\n" instead of just "\n".

Note also the use of double quotes (") and not single ('). Line end characters are interpreted as a literal backslash and letter when using single quotes.

Alternatively can also use the PHP_EOL constant instead, to make your code platform independent. The same code as a single line:

```
$s = 'xxx<br>' . PHP_EOL . 'yyy' . PHP_EOL;
```

Seeing as this is very basic stuff, I'd suggest you do some reading on basic PHP types, especially strings: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Note to mods ... I answered rather than voting to close as there did not appear to be an exactly identical question, albeit many others cover similar ground.